# ZF2 cacheing matched routes

Tags: events, caching, zend-framework2, router

in my application i have a route (Literal or segment) for every action. i am not using one global route for everything so as a result the number of routes has grown hugely with 44+ modules (and more in future) .

It is my understanding (from what i have seen in the code) that in every page request zend goes throw all this routes in a array ans searches for a match witch could be bottleneck for  the application (am i right?)

So i was thinking why not cache the matched routes in a db table with index to speed up the search ?

FIRST QUESTION : would this make the systems performance better?

so my first problem is skipping the system route matching mechanism. this is what i tried but it did not work :

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $em = StaticEventManager::getInstance();
        $em->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'onRoute'), 100);        
    } 

public function onRoute(MvcEvent $e)
{
    //var_dump($e->getRouteMatch());//->null routing has not been done yet
    /* @var $router \Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack */
    $router = $e->getRouter();
    //-------------------------------------created a dummy route
    $routeMatch = new \Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch(array(
        'controller' => 'Links\Controller\Items',
        'action' => 'view',
        'catId' => 0
    ));
    $routeMatch->setMatchedRouteName('app/links');
    $e->setRouteMatch($routeMatch);//set the dummy route
    //--------------------------------------------PROBLEM HERE
    //detach the onRoute event from routeListener
    $e->getApplication()
        ->getServiceManager()
        ->get('RouteListener')
        ->detach($e->getApplication()->getEventManager());
}
```

the detach method is executed but the onRoute event still gets executed and matches the url to the correct route. so how to bypass(skip|detach) route matching ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't detach the listener is because you're already in the `route` event. By that point all the listeners have been marshalled together and queued for execution.

Why not instead take the listener out of the equation beforehand?

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $events = $app->getEventManager();
    $shared = $events->getSharedManager();
    $services = $app->getServiceManager();

    $routeListener = $services->get('RouteListener');
    $routeListener->detach($events);                

    $shared->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'onRoute'), 100);
}
```

Comment: didn't know about listeners being marshalled. i am on vacation now , i'll try this when i get back to work, tnx

Comment: @Exlord, fwiw, in my tests it works fine with your `onRoute` method. I think I'd be inclined to just replace the `RouteListener` service itself by overriding it in my modules `service_manager` config. That would remove the need to detach the current listener and replace it in onBootstrap entirely.

Comment: well i needed to detach the listener only when there is a cache available otherwise it should continue with normal route matching and detaching the routeListener in bootstrap works as i wanted, tanks